# How to use findAll() method in Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a class/entity in Symfony and I am trying to use the `findAll()` method to get everything from a Table called Event:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('MYBUNDLE:Event')->findAll();
```

I get this error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 50 near 'e ': Error: Class 'e' is not
defined. 500 Internal Server Error - QueryException 1 linked
```

Here is my Entity:

```
class Event 
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Rposition")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_Owner", referencedColumnName="id" )
     **/
    private $idOwner;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="repeats", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $repeats;
```

What causes this error?  How do I correctly use findAll()?

Comment: Did you add an appropriate class annotation to the Event entity? Could you show it?

Comment: If you don't use multiple entity managers, you can actually only: `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MYBUNDLE:Event')->findAll();`. Did you use the correct Repository, it's always `VendorName + BundleName + "Bundle"`?

Comment: yes the repo si correct(i pute a fake one just there), and the annotation for event is: 'code'/**
 * Event
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="BladeTester\CalendarBundle\Repository\EventRepository")
 */
class Event

Comment: other strange (to me) things is that this works!!! $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
            ->getRepository('LapoMymeBundle:Event')->find($id);

Comment: Did you override the "findAll" method in your custom repository?

Comment: yes you spot the problem when I found it by myself...in another bundle this method is override, by this: public function findAll() {
        $q = $this->getEntityManager()
                    ->createQuery("SELECT e
                                   FROM $this->class e
                                   ORDER BY e.start ASC, e.end ASC");
        return $q->getResult();   but why it doesn't work? to me this query look right...

Comment: It's because "$this->class" could not be resolved as a proper entity class (probably it is null)

Comment: actually there is a function in the same repository: `private $class;

    public function setClass($class) {
        $this->class = $class;
    }` and then the findall() method with the declaration `$this->class` So are there linked in anyway even if there is no explict use in it? or where I can manipulate it for having a result? the findall() method is called over an Entity that is populated...

Comment: i've tryed to move the repo class on my own bundle...now the error change, no errors from symofony, but the app go in indefinite waiting and going on infinite loop unitl my browser is blocked by it!

Answer (score 4):

```
    $events = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Event')
        ->findAll();

    if (!$events) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No event found'
        );
    }

    return $this->render(
        'AppBundle:Event:index.html.twig',
        array('events' => $events)
    );
```

put this inside the desired controller function. Then render the specific twig which is in Resource/views/Event/index.html.twig

to print column values in index.html.twig , use 'for' loop for the array passed 'events', use variable from entity files such as,

{% for event in events %}

```
 {{ event.eventName }}
```

{% endfor %}

eventName is the variable in Entity 'Event'.